# Use Group by with mutate, case_when, any() and all() function in R

Tags: r, group-by, case-when, any

I have a `status_df` with id and status at each stage:

| id | stage | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 1 | Pending |
| 15 | 2 | Not Sent |
| 16 | 1 | Approved |
| 16 | 2 | Rejected |
| 16 | 3 | Not Sent |
| 16 | 4 | Not Sent |
| 20 | 1 | Approved |
| 20 | 2 | Approved |
| 20 | 3 | Approved |

I am trying to do a group_by ID and apply the following logic:

- if `any` stage for an ID has 'Pending' status, final_status column is 'Pending'
- if `any` stage for an ID has 'Rejected' status, final_status column is 'Rejected'
- if `all` stages for an ID are approved, final_status column is 'Approved'

I am trying this (not working):

```
final_status_df = status_df %>% select(id, status) %>% group_by(id) %>%
mutate(final_status = case_when(any(status)=="Pending" ~ "Pending",
any(status)=="Rejected" ~ "Rejected", 
all(status)=="Approved" ~ "Approved"))
```

Expected output (final_status_df):

| id | final_status |
| --- | --- |
| 15 | Pending |
| 16 | Rejected |
| 20 | Approved |

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were in the right direction with your attempt however, you closed `any`/`all` brackets early before comparison (`==`). Also since you only want 1 row for every `id` you can use `summarise` instead of `mutate` which will also avoid the use of `select`.

```
library(dplyr)

status_df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(final_status = case_when(any(status == "Pending") ~ "Pending",
                                     any(status == "Rejected") ~ "Rejected", 
                                     all(status == "Approved") ~ "Approved"))

#    id final_status
#* <int> <chr>       
#1    15 Pending     
#2    16 Rejected    
#3    20 Approved
```

Comment: Thank you. I was getting the error that any() takes logical relation, but I couldn't understand it was because I was placing the brackets wrong.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `summarise`instead of `mutate` (as `mutate` returns the output column with the same `length` as the input column and it is used to create/modify a column instead of summarising).

Also, an easier option is to convert to `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom order, drop the unused levels (`droplevels`) and select the `first` `levels` after grouping by 'id'

```
library(dplyr)
status_df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(final_status = first(levels(droplevels(factor(status, 
          levels = c("Pending", "Rejected", "Approved"))))), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#     id final_status
#  <int> <chr>       
#1    15 Pending     
#2    16 Rejected    
#3    20 Approved
```

---

In the OP's code, `any(status)` returns `NA`, instead it should be wrapped on a logical vector i.e. `any(status == "Pending")`.  Also, as mentioned above, it would be `summarise` instead of `mutate`

#### data

```
status_df <- structure(list(id = c(15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 20L, 20L, 
20L), stage = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), status = c("Pending", 
"Not Sent", "Approved", "Rejected", "Not Sent", "Not Sent", "Approved", 
"Approved", "Approved")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```